# Can I declare an object as a data member in a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object

So i got an abstract class Bee:

```
    abstract class Bee{
  private $name;
  private $number;
  private $health;

  public function __construct() {
  }
  /**
   * Functii set/get.
   */
  public function getName() { return $this->name; }
  public function setName($value) { $this->name = $value; }

  public function getNumber() { return $this->number; }
  public function setNumber($value) { $this->number = $value; }

  public function getHealth() { return $this->health; }
  public function setHealth($value) { $this->health = $value; }

  abstract public function hitted(); ///
}
```

And another 3 classes (Queen, Worker and Drone) that extends class Bee

```
/

**
 * Queen.
 */
class Queen extends Bee
{

  public function __construct() ///initializarea valorile Queen.
  {
    $this->setName("Queen");
    $this->setHealth(100);
      $this->setNumber(1);
  }


  public function hitted() /// Evenimentele declansate de primirea atacurilor.
  {
        $this->setHealth($this->getHealth() - 8);

  }
}

/**
 * Worker.
 */
class Worker extends Bee
{

  public function __construct() ///initializarea valorile Worker.
  {
    $this->setName("Worker");
    $this->setHealth(75);
      $this->setNumber(5);
  }


  public function hitted() /// Evenimentele declansate de primirea atacurilor.
  {
        $this->setHealth($this->getHealth() - 10);

  }
}

/**
 * Drone.
 */
class Drone extends Bee
{

  public function __construct() ///initializarea valorile Drone.
  {
    $this->setName("Drone");
    $this->setHealth(50);
      $this->setNumber(8);
  }


  public function hitted() /// Evenimentele declansate de primirea atacurilor.
  {
        $this->setHealth($this->getHealth() - 12);

  }
}
```

And i got an error when i am declaring Class Swamp with the following data members:

```
class Swarm{

    public $arr = array();
    public $queen = new Queen();
    public $worker = new Worker();
    public $drone = new Drone();

  public function __construct() {
    
  }


}
```

Here is my error:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\The Bee Game\background.php on line 93

The line 93 is in Swamp class:

```
public $queen = new Queen();
```

Comment: Leave $queen empty (`public $queen;`) and initialize it in the constructor (`$this->queen = new Queen();`)?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal - Post it as an answer instead so the OP can accept it and show others the issue has been resolved. And for you to get the deserved reputation.

Comment: it dosent even need the atribute 'this'

Comment: @GeorgeBusu - If you omit `$this` from `$this->queen = new Queen();`, it won't be stored in the class property but rather as a local variable that will only be available inside the constructor. `$this` isn't an attribute, its a reference to the current object. You can read more about [class properties here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and about [variable scopes here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: ohh... So much to learn. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do your initialization in your constructor

```
class Swarm {
    public $arr = array();
    public $queen;
    public $worker;
    public $drone;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->queen = new Queen();
        $this->worker = new Worker();
        $this->drone = new Drone();
    }
}
```